# Does HAPI FHIR Java API support chained parameters?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am trying to form a request like :

http://host/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Schedule?Schedule.actor:Practitioner=1234&Schedule.actor:Practitioner.location=5678&slottype=urn:oid:1.2.3|PrimaryCare&start=2016-08-08

Using HAPI FHIR Java API, how can I parse following params :

Schedule.actor:Practitioner=1234

Schedule.actor:Practitioner.location=5678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely supported.

Assuming you're creating a server, you would want a parameter on your resource provider method like:

```
@IncludeParam(allow={"Schedule:actor","Schedule:practitioner"}) 
Set<Include> theIncludes
```

Add `"*"` to the list of strings to just whitelist anything